# How do I delete row with condition on NA

Tags: r

First, how do I change NA into anything?

```
x[x==NA] <- "anything"
```

This does not work.

Also, how do I delete a row in a dataframe with condition on NA? For example:

```
    [,1][,2][,3]
[1,]  NA  NA 284
[2,] 233 182 249
[3,] 177 201  NA
```

I want to delete the row which has 2 or more NA in that particular row, so it will result in:

```
    [,1][,2][,3]
[2,] 233 182 249
[3,] 177 201  NA
```

---

Someone marked my question duplicated, but actually I want to control the amount of NA to delete a row, `complete.cases(x)` cannot provide any control to it.

Comment: I appreciate that you might have been unclear in your own mind as to what you wanted, but it's a little bit cheesy to change your question after it's been answered.  I've added a solution to your (updated) problem to @RHertel's answer ...

Comment: PS http://thomasleeper.com/Rcourse/Tutorials/NAhandling.html

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `complete.cases()`:

```
x <- x[complete.cases(x),]
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing the mistake @RHertel

Answer (score 1):

Here's another possibility:

```
x[!is.na(rowSums(x)),]
#[1] 233 182 249
```

**data**

```
x <- matrix(c(NA , NA, 284, 233, 182, 249, 177, 201, NA), byrow=TRUE, ncol=3)
```

To control the tolerance for `NA` values (e.g. exclude only rows with at least 2 `NA` values):

```
x[rowSums(is.na(x))<2,]
```

Comment: Thank you for the improvement / adaptation, @BenBolker

Answer (score 0):

To replace NAs:

```
x[which(is.na(x))] <- 0  # will be replaced by 0
```

To remove rows with two or more NA using apply function:

```
x[-which(apply(x, 1, function(xx) length(which(is.na(xx)))) >= 2),]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the others answer the 2nd part of your question. To answer your first part.

**If x is a vector**

```
x <- c(1,2,3,NA,4,NA)
x[is.na(x)] <- "anything"
```

**If x is a data frame**

```
x <- c(1,1,1,NA,1,NA)
df <- data.frame(var1=x,var2=x)
df$var1[is.na(df$var1)] <- -1
```